# How does one summarize with conditions into a single variable in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to use `summarise()` from dplyr after grouping data to compute a new variable. But, I would like it to use one equation for some of the data and a second equation for the rest of the data.

I have tried using `group_by()` and and `summarise()` with `if_else()` but it isn't working.

Here's an example. Let's say--for some reason--I wanted to find a special value for sepal length. For the species 'setosa' this special value is twice the mean of the sepal length. For all of the other species it is simply the mean of sepal length. This is the code I've tried, but it doesn't work with `summarise()`

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>%
   group_by(Species) %>%
   summarise(sepal_special = if_else(Species == "setosa", mean(Sepal.Length)*2, mean(Sepal.Length)))
```

This idea works with  `mutate()` but I would need to re-format the tibble to be the dataset I am looking for.

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>%
   group_by(Species) %>%
   mutate(sepal_special = if_else(Species == "setosa", mean(Sepal.Length)*2, mean(Sepal.Length)))
```

This is how I want the resulting tibble to be laid out:

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>%
group_by(Species)%>%
summarise(sepal_mean = mean(Sepal.Length))

  # A tibble: 3 x 2
  # Species    sepal_special
  # <fctr>          <dbl>
  #1 setosa           5.01
  #2 versicolor       5.94
  #3 virginica        6.59
  #>
```

But my result would show the value for setosa x 2

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
      # Species    sepal_special
      # <fctr>          <dbl>
      #1 setosa          **10.02**
      #2 versicolor       5.94
      #3 virginica        6.59
      #>
```

Suggestions? I feel like I've really searched for ways to use `if_else()` with `summarise()` but can't find it anywhere, which means there must be a better way.

Thanks!

Comment: Just change the `Species == "setosa"` in your initial try to `Species[1] == "setosa"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the `mutate` step, use `summarise` to get the `first` element of 'sepal_special' for each 'Species'

```
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  mutate(sepal_special = if_else(Species == "setosa", 
               mean(Sepal.Length)*2, mean(Sepal.Length))) %>% 
 summarise(sepal_special = first(sepal_special))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  Species    sepal_special
#   <fctr>             <dbl>
#1 setosa             10.0 
#2 versicolor          5.94
#3 virginica           6.59
```

---

Or instead of calling the `mutate`, after the `if_else` is applied, get the first value in `summarise`

```
iris %>% 
   group_by(Species) %>%
   summarise(sepal_special = if_else(Species == "setosa", 
           mean(Sepal.Length)*2, mean(Sepal.Length))[1]) 
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  Species    sepal_special
#  <fctr>             <dbl>
#1 setosa             10.0 
#2 versicolor          5.94
#3 virginica           6.59
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!! This is the one. I like the answer of taking the first value after `summarise`. Sometime when I'm not trying to get this report done, I'll have to dig into why this is needed with the `if_else` statement when it isn't necessary with just `summarise`.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Another option: since twice the mean is the same as the mean of twice the values, you can double the sepal lengths for setosa and then summarise:

```
iris %>% 
  mutate(Sepal.Length = ifelse(Species == "setosa", 2*Sepal.Length, Sepal.Length)) %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(sepal_special = mean(Sepal.Length))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Species    sepal_special
  <fct>              <dbl>
1 setosa             10.0 
2 versicolor          5.94
3 virginica           6.59
```